# How to install Python 3 on mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I am new here and I desperately need help with installing Python 3 on mac. I tried other answers but it didn't work... so I run `brew install python` and it shows `Warning: python@3.10 3.10.9 is already installed and up-to-date.`but when I run `python --version`, it shows `Python 2.7.18`

Question: How to swtich python 2.7 to python 3.10? Appreciate your help!!!

I have tried the command in [Learn To Setup Python 3 As A Default On your Mac](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

when I run `which python3`, it returns `/usr/bin/python3`, and then I run `echo alias python=/usr/bin/python3 >> ~/.zshrc` and I got `Permission denied`

Comment: That's because you installed python 3, which you run with `python3`, not `python`. Also, if your MacOS is so old that it still comes with python 2.7, _do not mess with the `python` executable_. It's required by the OS. It's why python3 is a separate executable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `python`, try `python3`